# Restore even earlier previous versions

Tags: windows, backup, windows-backup

When I right click a Windows file and click Properties and Previous Versions, I can only see very recent versions. Is there any way to restore even earlier versions? Can I, for example, run a full System Restore to get earlier previous versions of this Excel file?

[image]

Comment: No, All versions of the document are listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **System Restore** feature is limited in how much of your hard drive it is allowed to use for *previous versions*. The default setting under Windows 7 is to consume 5% of your drive to store previous versions of files.

If you want to access even earlier restore points, you have to allow System Restore to consume even more hard drive space.

You can configure this by going to:

- **Start** → **View Advanced System Settings** → **System Protection** tab

Under **Protection Settings**, select the drive you want to increase the limit on, and click **Configure**:

[image]

And then you can increase the **Max Usage** limit. The default is 5% of your SSD lost to previous versions; 10% would be better:

[image]

Comment: In Windows 10 it's under "Create a restore point" in the Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  A `System Restore` is *not* a backup of your entire system.  `System Restore` only affects system files, installed applications, Windows Registry, and other system settings.  It does not backup files or their versions.  If you do not have another backup of the file and `Previous Versions` does not show the version you are looking for, then more than likely, that version of the file is gone.

Comment: How come it stops displaying less recent previous versions that were there before?

Comment: I forget what the default settings are, but I believe it will keep 3 versions for some amount of time before it deletes old ones. Remember, file history is not a replacement for a real backup.

Comment: Where is the setting to change that?

Answer (score -1):

Please know that Previous Versions is a part of System Protection/System Restore in Windows. Since the previous version of files only created depend on when the system restore point was created, if there is no restore point, the version of file on that time period, can be not restore.

You can see this link to know how it works: 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/recover-data-files-in-windows-7-with-previous-versions/

To be assure that many version of previous files can be backup, you have to also enable file backup in Windows 7, the previous version feature can also track this to help you restore.